# API Platform - Custom subresource path doesn't work

Tags: api-platform.com

**API Platform version(s) affected**: 2.5.6

**Description**
Following this documentation: `https://api-platform.com/docs/core/subresources/#using-custom-paths`

I try to override the path (and security, and requirements) of a subresource.

It works for the security, but not for path (and so requirements).

**How to reproduce**
Clone this repo and follow the very small README :
https://github.com/bastoune/api-platform-issue-1581

Having this route with `debug:router` :
`api_organizations_users_get_subresource   GET      ANY      ANY    /v2/organizations/{id}/users.{_format}`
and this annotation :

```
 *      subresourceOperations={
 *          "api_organizations_users_get_subresource"={
 *              "method"="GET",
 *              "path"="/TEEEST/organizations/{organization_id}/users",
 *              "requirements"={"organization_id": StringHelper::UUIDv4Regex},
 *              "security"="is_granted('readOrganization', organization_id)"
 *          }
 *      }
```

The security works but not the rest.

If I remove the security, it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: I checked your User Entity and found that you have not put `@ApiSubResource `annotation on `$organisations`

Comment: @Vipulw, yes the SubResource is the User not the Organization

Comment: What I understand from subresource is that we can fetch `OneToMany` realtions of some Entity with that path by providing it's id. So, if you want to get all users of an organisation then you should add `@ApiSubResource` to `$user` in `Organization` Entity and do the subresource configuration there.

Comment: `@ApiSubresource` is well in the `Organization->$user`

And, wherever (In User OR Organiztion) I put the subresource configuration, i get the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned here : https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/1581#issuecomment-662503549

There is a bug with the operation name:

> Try with "users_get_subresource" as operation name (instead of
> "api_organizations_users_get_subresource").
> api-platform/docs#1109
>
> This PR was merge api-platform/docs#370 but this commit revert the changes api-platform/docs@b8304bc